# Release question from Hold status due to being Unclear

Tags: discussion

I am requesting [this question](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/80104/refused-access-to-make-changes-directly-to-the-live-site) about being denied access to a production website be released from HOLD status. I work in IT Security and can provide some insight from my work experience.

I feel important concepts such as Segregation of Duties and least privilege are not covered adequately.

**Update** I have edited the question. Does this version fit SE better?

Comment: `But somehow, he is not interested on handing over the FTP access to me.` -- Any answer to that question would require the ability to read your teammate's mind.

Comment: If your answer would focus on the security aspect, it is better suited to Security.SE.

Answer (score 3):

### This question needs to be edited before it can be re-opened.

As it is presently worded the question is unclear.  With the right edits, this question might be in scope for the site, but presently it is not.

> "Is there something which I am not able to understand?"

I have no idea what the OP might and might not be able to understand about the situation.  I'm pretty sure that is not the question OP intends to ask.  If OP can give us a more detailed question, we might be able to help.

In its current state, this question stands as an exemplar for why the "unclear" close reason is needed on this site.

Answer (score 2):

I think this question just needs very basic coverage of why's and why not's, and it already has them. The question is too vague to be worth a full on dissertation. Although I would personally be interested in examining your insights. They would not be helpful for the OP who hasn't grasped the bare basics yet.

Answer (score 2):

While I am often critical of post closings here, this one is justified.  I read it three times and am still not clear on what the OP was asking.  At least five other people feel the same way.

As it stands, the question is far too vague to answer.